# What is difference between logout and switch off?

Tags: logout

What is the difference between logout and switch off in wordpress 3.6 except below?

1.Logut - redirect to login screen of admin.

2.Switchoff - redirect to UI side.

Comment: The phrase "Switchoff" does not appear in the WordPress files. What page are you on when you see this options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [plugin User Switching installed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/)

From their FAQ:

> ### What does "Switch off" mean?
>
> Switching off logs you out of your account but retains your user ID in
>   an authentication cookie so you can switch straight back without
>   having to log in again manually. It's akin to switching to no user,
>   and being able to switch back.
>
> The Switch Off link can be found in your profile menu in the WordPress
>   toolbar. Once you've switched off you'll see a Switch back link in the
>   footer of your site.

### From my experience:

The plugin allows you to switch to another user's profile and see what that user sees without knowing their login credentials. After you're done, you click on switch off to go back to using your profile.

Comment: seems like your link is going nowhere